# Tomcat v7.0 failed to start from within Eclipse Jee Neon

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to start apache server and I am getting the following dialog box error:

[image]

Can someone show me how to fix this?

I tried to remove it and install it again but the error still remains.

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AtomikiDiplomatiki' did not find a matching property.
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.72
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Sep 14 2016 12:12:26 UTC
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.72.0
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\admin\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\admin\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\admin\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\ProgramData\Lenovo\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\admin\Google Drive\UCy\TAs\EPL445_2016\Labs_new\Eksaminiaia\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sophos\Sophos SSL VPN Client\bin;C:\windows\system32;;.
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 626 ms
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
??? 08, 2016 4:04:36 ?? org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.72
??? 08, 2016 4:04:37 ?? org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [290] milliseconds.
??? 08, 2016 4:04:37 ?? org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Users\admin\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\AtomikiDiplomatiki does not exist or is not a readable directory
    at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5247)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5436)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

??? 08, 2016 4:04:37 ?? org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AtomikiDiplomatiki]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AtomikiDiplomatiki]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5437)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

??? 08, 2016 4:04:37 ?? org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

??? 08, 2016 4:04:37 ?? org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 11 more

??? 08, 2016 4:04:37 ?? org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
??? 08, 2016 4:04:37 ?? org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
??? 08, 2016 4:04:37 ?? org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
??? 08, 2016 4:04:37 ?? org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
??? 08, 2016 4:04:37 ?? org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Server window, right click your server -> Go to add or remove -> remove all the wars files.
Again Right click server -> click clean
Again Right click server -> click Clean tomcat server work directory

Now, remove temp and work folder from the tomcat directory on the disk.

Then try running server.